# Emacs ZNC-ERC: How to make Customize save my preferences for all sessions

Tags: customize, session, erc

I am setting up my ERC client to connect to my ZNC IRC proxy server, and I am following [this Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ErcZNC). At the following step:

```
;; Configure
M-x customize-group znc RET
```

I am in the Emacs customize menu where I enter my ZNC server information, but this information is only saved for the current session, and I have to re-enter for every session.

Here is the menu, with a warning at the top indicating that I cannot save my custom settings:

[image]

I try to save with `C-x C-s`, but I get the following message in the mini buffer:
`Saving settings from "emacs -q" would overwrite existing customizations`. This doesn't make sense to me because I am not starting Emacs with a `-q` flag. I am using the default Emacs desktop file from my Ubuntu installation, which loads my `.emac.d/init.el` file.

I tried investigating [this Emacs wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomizingAndSaving#GetCustomizeToRecognizeChangedPreference), where it says: `Customize stores saved values (for future sessions) in the property saved-value`, but I'm not sure how to set this value, or where to begin with setting variables inside the Customize code. Any suggestions?

The only other hint I have is that clicking on `State` > `Show Saved Lisp Expression` at the bottom of the page, reveals my values as follows:

```
'(("irc.lukeswart.net" 5005 nil
   ((irc\.freenode\.net "zncuser" "foo"))))
```

**Update**

Thank you for the tips, it led me to discover the underlying problem and eventually fix it.

The problem was in my Ubuntu desktop file, saved under `~/.local/share/applications/emacs24.desktop`. Under this file, Emacs was starting with `emacs -q --load ~/path/to/my/init.el`. I initially missed this desktop file because I was checking under `/usr/share/applications/emacs24.desktop`. Anyway, here is the code that Customize adds to my `init.el`, although this should not be added manually:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(markdown-command "/usr/bin/pandoc")
 '(znc-servers (quote (("irc.lukeswart.net" 5005 nil ((irc\.freenode\.net "zncuser" "foo")))))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Comment: The error message you see comes from the function `custom-file`; it means that the value of `user-init-file` seems to be `nil`. What *is* the value of `user-init-file` in your setup?

Comment: Yes, the value `user-init-file` was `nil`. It turned out to be a problem with my desktop file after all, explained in my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you started Emacs normally, so that it read your init file, then yes, Customize should let you save any changes you make. If it does not, then that sounds like a bug.

If you did not start Emacs using switch `q` or `Q` (or equivalent, which means not to read your init file), and if you tried to save Customize settings and Emacs gave you that error message, then that is a bug, I think.

Please use `M-x report-emacs-bug`, describing just what you did so that the Emacs developers can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was looking at the wrong desktop file, where I was actually running `emacs -q --load /path/to/my/init.el`. Thanks for helping me diagnose the problem.